Hessian of hypersurfaces and warped products
I’m dealing with some Riemannian Geometry; there’s a question that is stuck in my mind.
It is known that every Riemannian manifold (M,g) is a warped product if I can find two smooth functions $u$ and $\lambda$ such that $$\nabla \nabla u= \lambda g.$$
Suppose that I have $M=I \times N$ a warped product with metric $$g=ds^2+\psi^2(s)g_N,$$ where $I$ is an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$, $N$ is closed and $\psi$ is a positive smooth function from $I$ to $N$.
Consider $\Sigma$ a closed, totally umbilic hypersurface embedded in $M$, different from $\{s\} \times N$.
I want to show that $\Sigma$ is a warped product.
My idea was to consider $u$ as above, and then show that the following holds:
$$\nabla \nabla (u|_{\Sigma})= \tilde\lambda g_\Sigma.$$
Thus, the thesis.
However, I’m not able to prove that equality (is it even true?). I imagine that umbilicity should play a crucial role.
In particular, I’m not able tu relate $\nabla \nabla u|_\Sigma$ to $\nabla^\Sigma \nabla^\Sigma (u|_\Sigma)$.
How can I solve this?
Thank you so much!
